# Conditional formatting of css class

Tags: css

Is it possible to add conditional formatting to change class on using hover effect on a div:

```
.resize:hover {
   height: 360px;
   z-index: 1;

   .font_white {
   color: blue;
   }
}


.font_white{
   color: white;
}
```

Is it possible to override font_white while hovering div with resize class? These classes are independent div's.

Comment: The way you've presented it, this isn't possible using only CSS. Depending on your markup, you may be able to do something though.

Comment: is this font_white class div exist inside resize div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not, not using pure CSS that is.

You can use JS, but without the code of your markup, it's hard to say what the best way is.

(Of course, if the font color is to be applied inside the div you hover, it is doable using CSS only, although not the way you describe it. But I assume you want to trigger style changes across the page by hovering a div.)

Comment: Thanks, I will then use JS to handle that per your sugestion, hope that one day CSS will have such future :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to achieve that with CSS.

If you can write a selector that matches both the element that is a member of the `resize` class and the element that is a member of the `font_white` class (which you would do using a [combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators) such as descendant, child or sibling) then you can use the combinator to achieve it.

For example:

```
.resize:hover ~ .font_white { ... }
```

would work if your HTML looked something like:

```
<button class="resize">Hover Me</button>
<section id="first">...</section>
<section id="second" class="font_white">...</section>
<section id="third" class="font_white">...</section>
```

You would need to select apropriate combinators for your particular HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite your CSS, you'll see that your desired effect is possible - and achievable without redefining the style declarations of your class.

**Example:**

```
.primary-text {
color: white;
}

.resize:hover {
height: 360px;
z-index: 1;
}

.resize:hover .primary-text {
color: blue;
}
```